# solution to $x^T xv = xx^T v$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am looking for a general solution to
$$
x^T xv = xx^T v
$$
with respect to $x$.

Here $x,v \in \mathbb{R}^d$ are column vectors, and $v$ is a constant vector.

I believe this is related to eigenvalues as we can translate the above to
$$
x^Tx = \lambda, xx^T = A.
$$

One solution I found is $av$ with a scalar $a>0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is tantamount to asking for some $x$ such that $$(x^\top v)x=(x^\top x)v$$

If $v=0$, then any $x$ works. If $v\ne 0$, then:

- the only solution with $x^\top v=0$ is for $x^\top x=0$, i.e. $x=0$.
- the solutions such that $x^\top v\ne 0$ satisfy $x=\frac{x^\top x}{x^\top v}v$, so they are in the form $tv$ for some scalar $t\ne0$. Such scalars are the ones that satisfy the equation $t^2(v^\top v)v=t^2(v^\top v)v$, i.e. all of them.

Putting everything together, $xx^\top v=vx^\top x $ if and only if $x$ and $v$ are linearly dependent.